# Jaspersoft Merging row cell if value is the same

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I would like to ask if this report template can be done in jaspersoft.

I have a data that looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to look like this, merging the value on first column (Provider) if they are the same value.
[image]

I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.20.0. Can someone show me how is it done on Design View? I've tried everything that I can but to no avail. Please I am stuck on this for 3 days already.